# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. React, Redux, Thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Please help, this has been bugging me for the last four days, I can't work it out.

I'm using react and redux to pull some data down that comes in a promse
I know I've got thunk installed but I dont know how to use it.
However my action comes back:  Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Action:

```
export const getShifts = () => dispatch => {
console.log('Fetching list of shifts for user...');
const request = API.get("StaffAPI", "/shifts", {
    headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
})
.then(response =>
    dispatch({type: 'SHIFTS_LOAD_SUCCESS', response})
)
.catch(err =>
    dispatch({type: 'SHIFTS_LOAD_FAIL'})
)
}
```

Reducer:

```
import _ from "lodash"
import { getShifts} from '../actions';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
switch(action.type){
 case SHIFTS_LOAD_SUCCESS:
    return { ...state, rota: action.response };
  }
 }
```

Component:

```
 componentWillMount() {
  this.props.getShifts();
  }
  renderPosts(){

console.log(this.props);
 return (

<div>
 <button onClick={this.logOut}>LogOut</button>
  <h4>hello{this.props.rotaData}</h4>
</div>
);


}


render() {
  return (
  <div className="row">
  {this.renderPosts()}

  </div>
);
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
 return{ rota: state.response };
}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getShifts: getShifts}) (StaffRota);
```

I'm new to all of this to please forgive me if its simple. Know-one  else has been able to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup `redux-thunk` when you create your store? it should be something like

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// Create store
const store = createStore(yourReducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Try to double check the thunk documentation https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk